# how to prepare python code to run from command line on different environment?

Tags: python-3.x, python-behave

how to run python(behave)code with environment parameters? e.g.
environment=X behave --tags @regression

what I have till now is

```
@given(u'user is on the firts page')
def step_impl(context):
    context.first_page = FirstPage(context)
    context.first_page.goto(url_config.URL["X env"])
```

and as dict URL

```
URL = {
    "X env": "https://...",
    "Y env": "https://..."
    }
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @0buz windows but I want to go with this code to pipe line so Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use environment variables for this. The pipeline script should include the following command to define which environment you want to run against:

```
export ENV=X_env
```

In your test scrip, get the environment variable and use that to get the appropriate url:

```
import os
    
@given(u'user is on the firts page')
def step_impl(context):
    context.first_page = FirstPage(context)
    execute_in_environment = os.environ.get("ENV")
    context.first_page.goto(url_config.URL[execute_in_environment])
```

Note that reading the environment variable - so this line: `execute_in_environment = os.environ.get("ENV")` is typically done at a higher level in the test framework, somewhere along with other config stuff. But going strictly by what is shared in the question I have added it to the step implementation, which isn't best practice.

If you want to try it out on your Windows station first, then set the environment variable in the CMD prompt using:

```
set ENV=X_env
```

So to run your tests against a specific environment you would run these commands (this is a Linux example):

```
export ENV=X_env
behave --tags @regression
```

Comment: thanks so much but now If I want to run the code from command line on linux(tfs pipeline) e.g how to run with env parameter? till now i was using behave --tags atregression but want to change it between different envs from cmd

Comment: also on win10 added ENV=X_env and than in CMD done that set ENV=X_env

Comment: You just run `behave --tags @regression`. No need for anything else as you have already set the environment variable in the previous command. So 2 lines in your cmd/shell: 1st to set env, 2nd to run tests.

Comment: @0buz I predicted that I need any linux inline env var inection command for pipeline

Comment: @0buz Only when I use that command  behave frontend\features\first_page.feature im on the Win so couldn't use export command

Comment: now try like that python -m behave -D test.environment=$environment frontend\features\first_page.feature --tags @d but nomather what I put as $environment the tests will run in the same env